# Generating File in Javascript for Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-os

I'm developping a Firefox OS application and i'm looking for generate a files with Javascript.

I know how to use [DeviceStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceStorage) and I also know that a file has property of [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

But I would like to generate files to full device memory. For example I would like to generate 1 file of 1Megabytes. But I have no idea how to do that. 
Someone has an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 1mB file you will need to fill an array with 1000000 bytes.

Then by using the constructor:

```
var typedArray = new ArrayBuffer(1000000);
var blob = new Blob([typedArray], {type: 'application/octet-binary'});
```

You will end up with a 1mB blob of binary data that could be saved to a file using standard api.

Comment: Correction: 1 Megabyte is **1048576** bytes not **1000000**

Comment: It alwais depends if you talk in miB or mB ... Windows will show a 1,048,576 bytes as 1mB where MacOs will show it as 1.049 MB ... So you are partially right, thx anyway.